# Aspnet compiler errors popups

Tags: asp.net

This aspnet_compiler.exe keeps popup-ing into my window almost every 30 seconds and it irritates me.
I already research how to fix this but seems I cant find any.
Hope somebody can help me fix this issue because I cannot work properly.

Thanks

[image: aspnet_compiler.exe]

Comment: Can you build your ASP.NET projects?

Comment: Try updating your operating system and restarting the computer, maybe reinstalling your ASP.NET features might help.